# How could I write environment URLs that should not be hardcoded in Bicep file?

Tags: azure, storage

How could I write environment URLs that should not be hardcoded in Bicep file ?

In this case, storageProfile uri and id.

Thx a lot !

My code in Bicep :

```
resource galleries_nicoGallery_name_nicoImageDef_-_-----_---- 'Microsoft.Compute/galleries/images/versions@2022-03-03' = {
  parent: galleries_nicoGallery_name_nicoImageDef
  name: '-.-----.----'
  location: location
  tags: {
    baseosimg: 'ubuntu1804'
    correlationId: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
    source: 'azureVmImageBuilder'
  }
  properties: {
    publishingProfile: {
      targetRegions: [
        {
          name: 'France Central'
          regionalReplicaCount: 1
          storageAccountType: 'Standard_LRS'
        }
        {
          name: 'West Europe'
          regionalReplicaCount: 1
          storageAccountType: 'Standard_LRS'
        }
      ]
      replicaCount: 1
      excludeFromLatest: false
      storageAccountType: 'Standard_LRS'
    }
    storageProfile: {
      osDiskImage: {
        hostCaching: 'ReadWrite'
        source: {
          uri: 'https://000000000000000000000000.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.vhd'
          id: storageAccounts_000000000000000000000000_externalid
        }
      }
    }
    safetyProfile: {
      allowDeletionOfReplicatedLocations: true
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to hardcode but this is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bicep [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/parameters) and [Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/variables). Every time you deploy a new Bicep you can provide new Parameter values directly from console. Otherwise, you can use [parameter file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/parameter-files).
You can also concat few values in a long string using parameters, variables or even function environment(). , which have predefined values, like "core.windows.net". More details in [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/linter-rule-no-hardcoded-environment-urls), some examples below.

Choose the best scenario for your situation.

```
param storageProfileSourceId string

var storageAccountName = 'somename'
var vhdId = 'someguid'
var storageProfileSourceUri = 'https://${storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/${vhdId}.vhd'

        source: {
          uri: storageProfileSourceUri
          id: storageProfileSourceId
        }
```